# reCAPTCHA causes a long horizontal scroll on RTL pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, recaptcha

When user clicks on "I'm not a robot" in reCAPTCHA v2, it adds a `div` to the page like this:

```
<div style="display: block; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 414px; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; height: 610px; z-index: 2000000000;">
```

The `div` contains another `div` with `gc-bubbleDefault` class. It causes a so long horizontal scroll because of `left: -10000px; top: -10000px;`.

How to avoid Google reCAPTCHA to sabotage my website?

Look at the firebug window. you can see the div appended to the page before the body close tag.
[image]

**EDIT**

I found out that this problem happens just on RTL pages due to negative left `-10000px` of element. Shame on Google for using such an idiot idea.

Is there any solution to solve it?

Comment: can you show working demo code.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved this by adding

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

to body element.

[this article](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/) can help you throw this.

hope it can help you

Comment: Why I never thought that could be as easy as setting `overflow-x: hidden;`? However, your solution was about to set also vertical overflow as hidden, while it doesn't make sense, Thanks for sharing this article!

Comment: Thanks Omid
it's true, it's better to set overflow-x to hidden.
I will edit my answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

Give `overflow: hidden;` on the `div`.

```
<div style="display: block; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 414px; 
            left: -10000px; top: -10000px; height: 610px; z-index: 2000000000;
            overflow: hidden;">
```

So, put it inside a `<div class="reCaptcha-Wrapper">` and apply these styles:

```
.reCaptcha-Wrapper div {overflow: hidden;}
```

I could see that there's a `dir="rtl"` in your document. That might also cause an issue. Can you remove that and check if it works? If you can't remove it, you can do it with CSS:

```
body > div:last { direction: rtl; }
#colorbox + div { direction: rtl; }
```

Or using JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $("body > div").last().css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: Hidden overflow needs to be assigned to the parent element. It's not supposed to work.

Comment: @Omid Can you wrap it up in a `<div>` and apply styles to the parent `<div>` this way...

Comment: reCAPTCHA is adding the `div` to the end of `body`. Wrapping reCAPTCHA has no effect on it. Downvote removed ;)

Comment: @Omid There should be a way... Can you show the init code and the  live page?

Comment: unfortunately can't show online demo. I attached a picture to the question.

Comment: @Omid Try this? `body > div:last-child {overflow: hidden;}`?

Comment: I found out that `rtl` direction of body causes the problem. When I remove the `direction: rtl` it will be OK

Comment: @Omid Ah... Okay, glad it got solved for you. Welcome! `:)`

Comment: @Omid Shall I add that in my answer so you could accept it?

Comment: it hasn't been solved yet. I can't remove RTL from my pages ;)

Comment: @Omid Try that: `$(function () { $("body > div").css("overflow", "hidden"); });`. This should work.

Comment: @Omid Try this at least: `body > div:last {
    direction: rtl;
}`

Comment: It's not going to be solved. This div wil be added on runtime.

Comment: @Omid Give me your init code. Please! I know how to solve it.

Comment: the `overflow-x` was the point. Hidden vertical overflow makes malfunctioning.

Comment: Yeah... Fine... You could say something like, it will also disable scrolling, I would have said it. Anyways, glad something helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to mess with the parent overflow css, so my solution is to add `right: 0!important` to the badge:

```
      .grecaptcha-badge {
        visibility: hidden;
        right: 0!important;
      }
```

This solution should be sufficient if the wrapper has a larger width than the badge itself.